# how to make count data

Tags: codeigniter, count

```
public function index()
{
    $yek = $this->input->post("KEY");
    $cek = $this->m_user->get('KEY' => $yek)->num_rows();//line 14
    $response = array();
    if ($cek > 1)
    {
        $list = $this->m_masalah->jenis();
    }
    foreach ($list as $key ) {
        $arr = array();
        $arr['ID_MASALAH']      = $key['ID_MASALAH'];
        $arr['MASALAH']         = $key['MASALAH'];
        $arr['JENIS']           = $key['JENIS'];
        array_push($response, $arr);
    }
    echo $json_response = json_encode($response);
}
```

this is my **erorr**

> **Parse error**:  syntax error, unexpected '=>'
>   (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ',' or ')' in
>   **E:\xampp\htdocs\sengketa_dpbt\application\controllers\Masalah.php** on line **14**

Comment: why you use get('KEY' => $yek) ? Why not get($yek) ?

Comment: what you are trying to do `$cek = $this->m_user->get('KEY' => $yek)->num_rows();`?

Comment: im trying to cacth data if data > 1

Answer (score -1):

The => symbol is used for assigning array elements, but you didn't declare it as an array here. Just make this change:

```
$cek = $this->m_user->get(array('KEY' => $yek))->num_rows();
```

Comment: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function num_rows() on array , change erorr

Comment: Ok, but if my answer helped you, you could still accept it as correct